# body:after appears on each printed page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing

I want to print two sheets of a Site. I use `body:after` only for the print. The problem is, that the content of :after appears on both printed pages.

```
body:after {
    content: "This printout is intended for the customer. Please keep it in a safe place.";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

For better understanding: I want to print two sheets with almost the same content, except for the after quote.

I clone the #content with Jquery's `clone()`, but I don't clone the whole body.
How can I fix this issue? Or is there even a better method of doing this whole thing?

Comment: You could create a DIV and print only whats inside that DIV using hidden attribute, assuming you are working on bootstrap that is. Also you should remove the position absolute from your CSS file

Comment: Im not working with a cms, but that trick should work anyway or?
And I want the quote on the bottom of the sheet. What else should I do then?

Comment: function PrintElem(elem)
{
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=400,width=600');

    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>' + document.title  + '</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
    mywindow.document.write('<h1>' + document.title  + '</h1>');
    mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

    mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
    mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/

    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();

    return true;
}

Answer (score 0):

When you clone whit jQuery, why not append "your quote" with jQuery after body? or where you want! and then you print it! And you decide on which page you want to be appended!

```
body.append('<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px;">Your quote</div>');
```